# Fixed menu пропадало на одной из section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать такой момент, что бы фиксированное меню не закрывало последнюю секцию на страничке, а пропадало или что бы просто уходило под него ( пробовал сделать через z-index, не особо успешно) 
Фиксированное меню реализовал таким образом:

сss:

```
nav.fixed-top > ul {
background: url(../img/maintoning.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
margin-top: -40px;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
opacity: 0.9;
}
```

script

```
if ($(window).width() >= '1000') {
$(window).scroll(function() {
var height = $(window).scrollTop();  
if(height > 780){
$('nav').addClass('fixed-top ');
} else{  
$('nav').removeClass('fixed-top ');
}
});
}   else{};
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index работает только с элементами у которых указан position. Попробуй указать фиксированному блоку и последнему section position и пропиши z-index

Comment: В данном примере указан базовый вариант, когда не стояла выше указанная задача. Я пробовал ставить абсолютное позиционирование для обоих блоков и z-index  - не получилось:(